# ServiceM8 Development in C#(Automatic Generation UUID)

Tags: c#, servicem8

I just wanna ask If I will be getting each UUID's (like, for Jobs, Company Contacts, Client, Categories, etc.) so they can sync to each modules, how can I retrieve or get it? (Using the ServiceM8's UUID Automatic Generation when creating a new one) Should I create one before getting? If yes, How? Is it the GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.servicem8.com/reference

> UUID is optional for record creation. If no UUID is supplied, a UUID will be automatically generated for the new record and returned in the response header as x-record-uuid.

Comment: I know this one, I read it already but is the x-record-uuid will be a straight forward records? Array or Json? thanks

Comment: It's a plain string value provided in a HTTP response header, you'd access it in the same way that you get the value of other HTTP headers like "Content-type" etc.